# i am conmfused about digital signature using assymetric key cryptography

Tags: java

in DIGITAL SIGNATURE in RSA  approach most people and you tuber have told PRIVATE KEY is used for  encryption and PUBLIC KEY for  decryption . When I searched about  working mechanism of RSA algorithm. I found that public key are used for encryption and private key are used for decryption. I  am  confused. so please someone help me?

Comment: No, Private decrypts, public encrypts.

Answer (score 0):

> PRIVATE KEY is used for encryption and PUBLIC KEY for decryption

It is exacly the other way around. Public key encrypts, private key decrypts.